# Variable type for cell

Tags: excel, vba, variables

I've tried `Dim CellA  As Long`, `As Integer` and `As Range` trying to save the address of a cell. In this example, (using Range) I get the

> Run Time Error 91 Object variable or with block variable not set

on line 4: `CellA = Cells(ActiveCell.Row - 1, 1)`

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim ColA As String
Dim ColB As String
Dim CellA As Range

CellA = Cells(ActiveCell.Row - 1, 1)
If (Len(Cells(ActiveCell.Row - 1, 1) > 0)) Then
    ColA = CleanCode(Cells(ActiveCell.Row - 1, 1))
    ColB = CleanCode(Cells(ActiveCell.Row - 1, 2))
    If (ColA <> ColB) Then
        MsgBox (Cells(ActiveCell.Row - 1, 2))
        Range(Cells(ActiveCell.Row - 1, 1)).Select
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

I would like to replace all my `Cells(ActiveCell.Row...)` references with variable references including my range select (which obviously doesn't work as it stands).

**FYI:** This routine generates a message box with the contents of a (hidden) column B cell when what I type in a column A cell doesn't match that column B cell. I wrote it to help me memorize my lines for my video head-shots.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear - you have an object variable that is not `Set`.

Comment: Agreed. I understand the argument was asking for a different type of variable. I took the word object as a generic term not a variable type. NO excuse.

Answer (score 3):

Because CellA is an object you can't do this

```
CellA = Cells(ActiveCell.Row - 1, 1)
```

you have to use the `Set` keyword like this

```
 Set CellA = Cells(ActiveCell.Row - 1, 1)
```

Comment: Thank you Glenn G. That took care of it. Did not think about it being an object. I still have the issue of trying to position the cursor back to the offending cell. I gather either the Range command is not the right one or I need a different type argument.

Comment: As for why you're getting that specific error, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58734975/1188513). Or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58844925/1188513)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon. I see. Thank you for your response. I replaced the range statement with ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Activate. Is that the proper solution?

Comment: It has the enormous advantage of being explicit about what's going on. Not ideal that it uses `Activate`, but at least it's explicit about it. See [how to avoid select & activate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/1188513)

Answer (score 3):

Ranges are objects.  You need to use the keyword `Set` to make an object assignment.

> ```
> Set CellA = Cells(ActiveCell.Row - 1, 1)
> ```

- `CellA` is never used
- These extra parenthesis `(Len(Cells(ActiveCell.Row - 1, 1) > 0))` are just clutter.
- Avoid using parenthesis like this:`MsgBox (Cells(ActiveCell.Row - 1, 2))` could cause issues.
- Replace `Range(Cells(ActiveCell.Row - 1, 1))` with `ActiveCell.Offset(-1,2)` or `ActiveCell(-1,2)`

  Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
      Dim ColA As String
      Dim ColB As String
      Dim CellA As Range
      Dim CellB As Range

  ```
  Set CellA = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 1)
  Set CellB = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 2)

  If Len(CellA.Value) > 0 Then
      ColA = CleanCode(CellA)
      ColB = CleanCode(CellB)

      If (ColA <> ColB) Then
          MsgBox CellB
          ColA.Select
      End If
  End If
  ```

  End Sub

Comment: Wow. Much better. Thanks for the improvements.

Comment: I did need to change a couple of things. I changed the offsets from -1,1 to -1,0 and from -1,2 to -1,1. And the ColA.Select to CellA.Select. It works exactly as I need. Thanks.